# Spring boot & react - Cookies are not being set via browser, but are set on postman

Tags: reactjs, spring, cookies

I am trying to set cookies, but they are not being set on the browser, but they do when I use postman to call the request.

Both sever & client run on HTTP.
I can see the cookies being set in the response of the request in the network tab, but on application tab -> cookies  localhost:3000 are not being set.

Thats how I set my  cookies:

[image]

And that's how I call the request with react:

[image]

Why are the cookies not being set? Is there something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

First guess is you are setting cookies to `127.0.0.1` and trying to read them on `localhost`.